# Problemas com o controle ActiveX (botão de opção), contando valores de acordo com a marcação do botão

Tags: microsoft-excel

Eu quero contar os valores de acordo com a marcação do botão, para cada clique em cada botão, eu pretendo adicionar 1,2,3 em cada células A29: A31. Também serve em apenas uma célula desde que altere o valor 1,2,3 para cada botão clicado de acordo com a numeração dos botões, Ex: Botão 1 = "1", Botão 2 = "2", Botão 3 = "3". Como eu faço isso ??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa utilizar o VBA, mas não entendi direito o que precisa. Ao clical o OptionButton1, insere o valor 1 em A29? E OptionButton2 o valor 2 em A30 ou A29?

Answer (score 2):

Elienay Junior, montei essa rotininha abaixo rapidinho... por favor, veja se te ajuda:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Range("A30").Value = ""
    Range("A31").Value = ""
    preencherCelulas (29)
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Range("A31").Value = ""
    preencherCelulas (30)
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    preencherCelulas (31)
End Sub

Sub preencherCelulas(Limite As Long)
Dim strCelula As String
Dim bytConta As Byte

    strCelula = "A" & Limite
    bytConta = 1

    For y = 29 To Limite
        Range(strCelula).Value = bytConta
        bytConta = bytConta + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW: É recomendado a declaração como Long. Por inúmeros motivos, mas leia [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/7690982) e entenda a razão. Pois em computadores modernos, este ganho de memória não é significante, podendo até utilizar a mesma memória de um Long em sistemas 32 bits. Já os possíveis erros são inúmeros...  Não utilize o Integer no número da linha, se a planilha for muito grande irá causar um overflow

Comment: E evite o `.Select`, ele é lento e suscetível a erros. Ao invés de `Range("A31").Select: ActiveCell.Value = ""` você pode fazer `Range("A31").Value = ""`

Comment: @ danieltakeshi, Essa declaração como "Long" como seria?? Sou leigo em VBA, entendo pouquíssimas coisas, só entendo mesmo as fórmulas do Excel do básico ao avançado, ainda não comecei a estudar VBA. Essa declaração é uma variável?? ou seria no lugar de "Private Sub ()" ??

Comment: @FabioIn, eu consegui montar uma fórmula do Excel, utilizando células auxiliares com outras fórmulas. Porém a contagem foi separada, se o Botão 1 = V = valor "1" se for falso = "0" então a contagem sera 1/0/0, 0/2/0, 0/0/3 e assim por diante. Vou da uma olhada nesse seu código e ver como ele reage

Comment: @Elienay Junior, okay.

Comment: Mude de `Sub preencherCelulas(Limite As Integer)` para `Sub preencherCelulas(Limite As Long)`. Ou ao declarar uma variável `Dim variavel As Long`

Comment: @danieltakeshi, valew!